# Increment index in for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to update the start 'i' index to the end 'i' index after every iteration. How do I go about this? So printing it would give me (1, 11), (11, 21), etc.. Thanks!

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    print(i, i+10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is this:

```
for i in range(1, 100, 10):
    print(i, i+10)
```

Comment: This won't work. The main problem is, ```i``` will start with the value 1, then will be assigned the value 11, will print 11, 21, and then will be assigned the value 2 due to ```for i in range(1, 100)```.  A second problem is that it starts from 11,21, whereas the question asks for a sequence starting from 1, 11. To update the loop variable this way, use a ```while``` loop. For a ```for``` loop, you can use Enzo's answer.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I made this mistake because of the time I hadn't used python. However it is a better idea to pass a third argument in step

Comment: For simple codes like this, please test your answer before posting, in the future.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `step` argument of `range`:

```py
for i in range(1, 100, 10):
    print(i, i+10)
```

outputs

```
1 11
11 21
21 31
31 41
41 51
51 61
61 71
71 81
81 91
91 101
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method I'd like to suggest:

```
for i in range(10): # So i goes from 0 to 9
    print( 10*i+1 , 10*(i+1)+1 )
```

It prints:

```
1 11
11 21
21 31
31 41
41 51
51 61
61 71
71 81
81 91
91 101
```